# CSRF token not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I m working on laravel login and everything works fine in localhost but when i moved to live server its throwing page expired error even though i have added `csrf token`

My form is like this

```
 <form  method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" role="form">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                    @endif

                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                    @endif

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Sign in</button>
                </form>
```

I have tried clearing server cache  with `php artisan cache:clear` and restarting my apache 2 server
I have also tried to clear session in `config/framework/session` folder and also in `config.framework/views`

Even though it still persist

Can anyone please help me ???
Thank you

Comment: do you have `.env` file ?

Comment: yes i have .env file

Comment: execute `php artisan key:generate` and check what happens then.

Comment: yes i did no help :/

Answer (score 2):

Are your session cookies set to secure? in `config/session.php` make sure `'secure'=>false` if you are not using https.

Comment: Sounds like the session cannot be saved. Can you verify if apache can write to the session directory `storage/framework/sessions`. that is if you are using the file driver for sessions

Comment: Yes it has read write and excution permission 
i changed it permission using chmod –R 777 sessions 

and its current persmission showing – rw– r––  r– –

Comment: can you verify the session is working? does the token change each time you re-load the form?
can you post what you have in your `config/session.php`? also any .env variables starting with `SESSION_`.

Comment: no the token value does not change on page loading apparently it seems to be same even after refreshing the page
 In session file i have this   `  'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false), `  along with other laravel default setting i didn't change anything
 in .env i have this `SESSION_DRIVER=file` 
nothing else with prefix SESSION_

Comment: ok sessions are working. maybe try to clear your cookies and try again. If you have changed the application key in your .env file could cause the problem. Also verify the time on the server is correct.